# How to delete a message that is still delayed?

Tags: drupal

yesterday I sent an e-mail. I got a message that it is delayed. I regret sending this mail.

Comment: Yeah, it really sucks when your massage gets delayed.

Comment: Regrettable emails are all too common these days. Perhaps a massage will help you relax and not worry about it so much.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing your identity or pretending someone else sent it.

Here, in Australia, there is a Journalist who got caught plagiarizing work (on his website) so he claimed someone hacked his website and they did it. Maybe tactic this could work for you.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_W._Richards